# Is CodeMotion's Stack Overflow Coding Challenge official?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this coding challenge](https://www.codemotion.com/coding-challenges/stack-overflow/stack-overflow-coding-challenge-264) on a Facebook ad. I couldn't search for more details about it on Google and I was wondering: **is this challenge affiliated with Stack Overflow**?

Comment: *"... is the initiative promoted by Stack Exchange Legal that consists of 1 test to be carried out online, aiming to reward the skills and merit of the best operating minds, whether at a professional level or at an amateur level, in the field of computer programming."* - I find that highly unlikely

Comment: And that's not even mentioning the blatant typo in the page [title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fg0K.png)

Comment: And the blatant typos throughout: *"Each Participant shall ensure that the* ***personal data*** given when registering ***are true*** and correct."*

Comment: But then considering the testing is done through hackerrank, which is literally a marketing company trying to sell you based on your programming skill in their arguably *awful* tests, I'm not surprised it would be junk.

Comment: That's kind of messed up.  Borderline phishing.  Definitely false advertising.

Comment: @Nick: Are you considering that to be a typo because you consider "data" to be singular? I'd argue that while unusual, "are true" is fine for at least some style guides. (See https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/07/data-is-or-data-are.html for example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet It's funny you mention that, I'm using it as a mass noun (i.e. the singular, as that is the every day usage most will be familiar with), but I have recently had another discussion about why I think a lot of the APA style guide isn't great :P. Nevertheless, I see your point. *However*, I draw the line at *"...program* ***codes*** *at a professional..."* :shivers:

Comment: @Nick: "codes" is an interesting one. I've tended to think of it as an uncountable noun (I'm in the UK), so I _always_ use the singular form. But if I write in several languages in one project, I suppose I have written "codes" (several groups of the uncountable noun). I imagine that "waters of the world" is a reasonable parallel - water is an uncountable noun, but it can be grouped, and thus becomes "waters".

Comment: This has become an interesting debate in relation to variations of English. "Codes" has become popular in English-speaking India, and I don't know whether it is regarded as correct by experts who understand Indian English, but I am wary of correcting someone else's dialect.

Comment: @halfer I don't think *"waters of the world"* _is_ a reasonable parallel, one of the definitions of water is *"a stretch or area of water, such as a river, sea, or lake"*, which _is_ countable, while in CS *"code"* (as in source code) is indeed a mass noun. See [Is it wrong to use the word “codes” in a programming context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context), especially Peter's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/20474).

Comment: @Nick: I won't put a lot of effort into this debate, since I use "code" singular very firmly. My comments are partly devil's advocacy, and partly a note that speakers of English that is not British/American English may determine what is correct within their own changing language rules. Nevertheless, I don't see that water is different to code - both are uncountable, and the difference I think you are indicating with water is that it has boundaries, which differentiates one water from another. But code has boundaries too - files, folders, projects.

Comment: (I respect Peter's work greatly, since he is a very assiduous editor over at Stack Overflow. I am sure he is correct for British and American English. He may also be correct for Indian English, but I would not want to get into the practice of telling Indians how to use their language. I think there might be an ESL site within Stack Exchange?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow for Teams is a sponsor of the Codemotion event.

Comment: I will accept it because you are a staff member. Is there any public statement of sponsorship from Stack Overflow for Teams?

Comment: @TheodoreTsirpanis can you explain what you are looking for regarding a public statement?

Comment: I was just curious. Little information is available about that competition.

Comment: @TheodoreTsirpanis you can read more detailed information provided by Codemotion here - https://extra.codemotion.com/stack-overflow-coding-challenge-tc/